# build() works in IDE but not in EXE

Tags: python, google-api, pyinstaller

I am working on a python project which includes using the Youtube\Google API, accessing public playlists.
The code works fine in the Pycharm IDE but after using Pyinstaller to build it into an .exe file, it crashes and prints 'Crashed at youtube build stage'

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build    
try:
    os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = json_path
    credentials = google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(json_path)
    print("credentials=",credentials)
    youtube = build(serviceName='youtube', version='v3', developerKey=yt_api_key, num_retries=3,credentials=credentials)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Crashed at youtube build stage \n\nError: {e}")
try:
    youtube_playlist=youtube.playlists().list(part='contentDetails,id',id=youtube_playlist_id)
    youtube_playlist=youtube_playlist.execute()
except Exception as e:
    print(e,"\nERROR HERE")
```

When running on the IDE the build succeeds, but fails at the 2nd try except section.
The error given is :

```
('invalid_scope: Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided.', {'error': 'invalid_scope', 'error_description': 'Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided.'})
```

I looked at the google API and the playlists() method and I didn't find any place to use the Oauth credentials there.

When running on the EXE it simply prints :

```
Crashed at youtube build stage

Error: name: youtube  version: v3
```

According the the build() documentation found here https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.discovery-module.html#build
I found that the function raises an error when it can't create an mTLS connection.
Why can't it do so when the code is ran from an .exe file but manages when called from the IDE?

I thought the .exe created with Pyinstaller would work as it does on Pycharm, but it appears not to.
Not sure why TLS fails to set up.

Edit: added credentials and Oauth2 and another error appears.
It manages to build it but right afte

Comment: Does your code work outside PyCharm if you call it from your cli?

Comment: Seems not, I tried doing it in the python CLI though.

Comment: I think if you look around on stack you will find a number of questions relating to the same thing.

Comment: If you enable your environment (if you created one which you should) and try to execute it, it has to work in order to ever have a working exe. What error do you get if you run it outside the IDE?

Comment: I edited the post as I changed the code(added credentials and Oauth2 for windows apps)
Right now after adding credentials it doesn't work on neither the IDE nor the app.